# No memory leak but All Allocations keep increasing

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management

I have two viewcontrollers and I am switching between both with using Segue class.

```
-(IBAction)selectActiveAccount:(id)sender
{
    [self setActiveAccountTag: [(UIButton *)sender tag]];
    [self dyeObjects];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mainScreen" sender:[(NMBButton *)sender buttonUserName]];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"mainScreen"]) 
    {
        NMBViewController *mScreen = [segue destinationViewController];
        [mScreen setActiveUser:sender];
    }
}
```

Instruments not show any leak on both viewcontroller classes however over all allocations keep growing during switch viewcontroller. Every time when switch it increase 1 - 2mb. I am caching images on both view controllers but I am deleting all on viewDidDisappear. Any ideas would be very welcome.

Edit: as I mentioned there is no leak on instruments. I am using accessor method to set objects and checked all allocated objects. All of them are released. First time I am facing this kind of issue. If you release all objects memory usage shouldn't keep increasing.

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    SDImageCache *imageCache = [SDImageCache sharedImageCache];
    [imageCache clearMemory];
    [imageCache clearDisk];
    [imageCache cleanDisk];
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    logS(@"viewDidUnload");
    [dashboardTableView release];
    dashboardTableView = nil;
    [dashboard release];
    dashboard = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [dashboard release];
    [dashboardTableView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: need more code to help you out. Do include viewDidDisappear and also your dealloc method

Comment: Looks like there six objects of 1.25 MB each. What are those? Go into the details for those and look at the stack traces.

Comment: thank you, did not see that 6 object it was keep increasing. it was core graphic. thank you so much. second eyes always better. actually weird part is i was setting background picture again and again that was the reason but what i couldn't understand why it wasn't leaking on instruments.

Comment: That looks like a retain cycle. Leaks cannot find everything.

Comment: first time i am working with Storyboard / Segue. when another view controller called and existing one left the scene did unload and dealloc not called if i am not wrong i have to set everything to nil on viewDidDisappear am I?

Comment: 1. what is the allocation count of your viewControllerSubclasses? 2. what kind of segues do you have? 3. assuming push segues, you are continuously allocating new instances of your view controllers and pushing them